# Unable to register client to eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

My Eureka server is running, but when I try to run client application I get following error:

```
DiscoveryClient_PRODUCT/172.16.2.67:Product:9090 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1017) [eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:931) [eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.(DiscoveryClient.java:441) [eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.(DiscoveryClient.java:304) [eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.(CloudEurekaClient.java:51) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:179) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9785688c.CGLIB$eurekaClient$1() [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9785688c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6bcab8ca.invoke() [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9785688c.eurekaClient() [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:359) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:176) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.getApplications(Unknown Source) [na:na]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.java:120) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.start(EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.java:97) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) [spring-boot-1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at com.example.config.Product.ProductApplication.main(ProductApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]

2017-05-22 12:59:25.108 WARN 9652 --- [ restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Using default backup registry implementation which does not do anything.
2017-05-22 12:59:25.116 INFO 9652 --- [ restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2017-05-22 12:59:25.118 INFO 9652 --- [ restartedMain] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2017-05-22 12:59:25.159 INFO 9652 --- [ restartedMain] c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Registering application Product with eureka with status UP
2017-05-22 12:59:25.161 INFO 9652 --- [ restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1495438165160, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2017-05-22 12:59:25.164 INFO 9652 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : DiscoveryClient_PRODUCT/172.16.2.67:Product:9090: registering service...
2017-05-22 12:59:25.315 WARN 9652 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient : Request execution failure with status code 500; retrying on another server if available
2017-05-22 12:59:25.319 WARN 9652 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : DiscoveryClient_PRODUCT/172.16.2.67:Product:9090 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:810) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:103) [eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:87) [eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]

2017-05-22 12:59:25.321 WARN 9652 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator : There was a problem with the instance info replicator

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:810) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:103) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:87) [eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

On the Discorvery Server Console I'm getting below error:

```
2017-05-22 14:21:04.554 ERROR 11672 --- [nio-8761-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
        at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119) ~[javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:911) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:875) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:829) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]

2017-05-22 14:21:11.405  INFO 11672 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
```

The microservice keeps trying to connect to the server every 10sec, but fails. What may be the cause for this?

Microservice(client) application.yml is as following:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Product
server:
  port: 9090

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Eureka Server is up and running on 8761 port:

```
2017-05-22 14:35:53.731  INFO 13488 --- [      Thread-10] e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration : Started Eureka Server
2017-05-22 14:35:53.774  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http)
2017-05-22 14:35:53.778  INFO 13488 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8761
2017-05-22 14:35:53.785  INFO 13488 --- [           main] c.e.c.E.EurekaServerApplication          : Started EurekaServerApplication in 8.619 seconds (JVM running for 12.336)
```

Comment: I'm using SpringBoot annotations

Comment: Eureka Server is running on port 8761, and same port is defined in application.yml of client. What else may be the cause?

Comment: 2017-05-22 14:35:53.731  INFO 13488 --- [      Thread-10] e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration : Started Eureka Server
2017-05-22 14:35:53.774  INFO 13488 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http)
2017-05-22 14:35:53.778  INFO 13488 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8761
2017-05-22 14:35:53.785  INFO 13488 --- [           main] c.e.c.E.EurekaServerApplication          : Started EurekaServerApplication in 8.619 seconds (JVM running for 12.336)

Comment: Same problem occurs with auto configuration too

Comment: localhost:8761 takes me to eureka server, but no instances available in "Instances currently registered with Eureka"

Comment: Yes my bootstrap.yml has:spring:
  application:
    name: Prodcut

Comment: Let me try with that

Comment: Build fails with the below exception : Exception: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient! javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter: javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter

Comment: For Eureka server I'm getting below error : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project eureka: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [eurekademo.EurekaApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerConfiguration: javax/ws/rs/core/Application: javax.ws.rs.core.Application

Comment: yes using maven

Comment: mvn spring-boot:run , using this command I'm trying to run, but  the build fails for client

Comment: Executing "java -jar eureka-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" gives error. How to execute jar files?

Comment: What's the error? Did you append **.jar**?

Comment: Yeah didnt append .jar.

Comment: After executing service jar I'm getting this error : 
2017-05-22 15:48:59.388 ERROR 11124 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [hello.EurekaServiceApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerConfiguration

Comment: Getting this error when I try to run the client:

Comment: ERROR 14964 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration';

Comment: nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter

Comment: What is the classpath for javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter  in your case?

Comment: In my C:\Users\Divya\.m2\repository\javax\ws\rs folder there are both javax.ws.rs-api and jsr311-api. And I'm unable to delete javax. How do I resolve the conflict?

Comment: I built the sample code as it is, still it is giving this error.

Comment: Stop all java processes, rename .m2 folder, do a fresh clean install on the sample code and try.

Comment: Unable to rename .m2, says already in use

Comment: It's in use because it's being used by some processes. If you are unable to find and stop them, just do a reboot and rename.

Comment: renamed and trying to build again

Comment: The client from sample code registered with the eureka server.Now I'll check my code with it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Copying the pom.xml from the sample code to my project worked.

Comment: yeah, seems so!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the reason behind this issue is probably due to conflict of class `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter` from two different versions of jar(**javax.ws.rs-api** and **jsr311-api**). The **pom.xml** used in the project had dependency on both of these jars and hence the issue. This was rectified by copying the working **pom.xml** provided by Spring's [sample code](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/) for registration and discovery.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I generated the project from spring initialzr.

The Eureka Server shows URL with port 8761 but it actually runs on default embedded tomcat port 8080.

adding server.port=8761 (or whatever you want to configure) in application properties of Eureka Server project

Using that port with Eureka Server host add eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=: in application properties of  Eureka Client resolved the issue.

Make sure to have eureka client project running in different port than eureka server project